# Creating an instance from inside a datalab instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

Hi does anyone know how to create and run an instance from a jupyter notebook and/or a datalab instance in the cloud?

I'm trying to run a large computation and I want to divide the tasks into several VMs in the cloud. Is there anyway I could create and run an instance from my datalab notebook?

For ex:
I want to run every loop of a 10 iteration for loop in a different VM. For that I need to create and run a VM from inside my datalab notebook where my code is.
Thanks for the help!

Edit:
This is an example of a startup script I'm using.

gcloud compute instances create instance11 \

--metadata  startup-script=‘#! /bin/bash

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install python3.6

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

sudo python get-pip.py

pip --version

pip install pandas --user

pip install scipy --user

pip install scikit-learn --user

pip install sklearn —user

pip install matplotlib --user

gsutil cp gs://bucket/datafile /home directory

gsutil cp gs://bucket/pythonfile /homedirectory

' --machine-type n1-standard-32

Comment: Have you tried using `gcloud`? It's bundled with Datalab, so you should be able to run this in a notebook cell: `gcloud compute instances create...`.

Comment: Yes it worked but I was wondering how I'd pass commands to the VM without having to manually SSH into it. I tried using a startup script but it doesn't get executed. Thanks

Comment: I think you're trying to build your own distributed computing cluster. For that, you shouldn't use Datalab, which is meant to be a user facing experience for data manipulation. Take a look at GKE or GCE instance groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commentary on your question is good and I agree with it. With the proper dependencies installed, you can make calls to `gcloud` commands to spin up VMs from your Jupyter notebook. For example, to spin up an n1-standard-1 Debian 9 instance in us-east1:

```sh
gcloud compute instances create <name> --image-family debian-9 
    --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --zone=us-east1-b
```

> I was wondering how I'd pass commands to the VM without having to manually SSH into it. I tried using a startup script but it doesn't get executed.

The cloud-native mechanism for doing this would indeed be to use a startup script to ensure your machine builds are reproducible, rather than logging in via SSH and running commands imperatively at a shell.

If you have problems running a startup script, I recommend creating an instance and attempting to run it manually as the `root` user. Otherwise, post an example of the script you are using so we can assist further.

---

Finally, as [this commenter noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174550/creating-an-instance-from-inside-a-datalab-instance#comment91338084_52174550), you may be attempting to solve the wrong problem by misusing the framework within which you're operating. If this proves challenging, you should consider taking a step back to define a more robust mechanism using the native Google tools and your own code to implement your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm looking into using docker containers to achieve this.